# Import in vectors an image from photoshop to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a logo in photoshop which consists on 2 layers:

1. Text
2. Image (vertical bars, with rounded top and bottom)

Those bars top/bottom are not perfectly round. So I would like to transfer it to Illustrator and convert it to outlines.

I tried to import to Illustrator the image in transparent png and svg...however the "Create Outlines" menu option is grayed out.

How can I import a logo from PS to AI and convert it to outlines?

Comment: You can draw vertical shape in photoshop. it's under rounded rectangle tool. To export shapes, lines and paths to illustrator use "Export to" option in the File menu.

Comment: Google "Illustrator Create Outlines". It doesn't do what you expect it to, instead it is used to convert TEXT to SHAPES.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an *image* in Photoshop (i.e. a raster image and not a shape layer or work path<sup>*</sup>) and your problem is precision (e.g. "not perfectly round") then you're pretty much out of luck.

The "Convert to Outlines" function in Illustrator has nothing to do with creating paths from images but from *live type*. There is [Image Trace](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/image-trace.html) that does what you want; *But*, it isn't a precision tool and won't get you any "perfectly round" shapes.

You'd be much better off opening the PSD in Illustrator and recreating the shapes you need by tracing the existing shapes using Illustrator's drawing tools (and creating logos in Illustrator from the get go in future).

---

<sup><sup>*</sup> If you do have shape layers or paths in Photoshop then you can either open the PSD directly in Illustrator or go *File → Export → Paths to Illustrator...* in Photoshop.</sup>